# Relations between p norms

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

The $p$-norm on $\mathbb R^n$ is given by $\|x\|_{p}=\big(\sum_{k=1}^n
|x_{k}|^p\big)^{1/p}$. For $0 < p < q$ it can be shown that $\|x\|_p\geq\|x\|_q$ ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76016/is-p-norm-decreasing-in-p), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69125/inequality-between-ellp-norms)). It appears that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ a number of opposite inequalities can also be obtained. In fact, since all norms in a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent, this must be the case. So far, I only found the following: $\|x\|_{1} \leq\sqrt n\,\|x\|_{2}$([3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Relations_between_p-norms)),  $\|x\|_{2} \leq \sqrt n\,\|x\|_\infty$ ([4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192974/inequality-between-norms-of-vector)). Geometrically, it is easy to see that opposite inequalities must hold in $\mathbb R^n$. For instance, for $n=2$ and $n=3$ one can see that for $0 < p < q$, the spheres with radius $\sqrt n$ with $\|\cdot\|_p$ inscribe spheres with radius $1$ with $\|\cdot\|_q$.

It is not hard to prove the inequality (4). According to Wikipedia, inequality (3) follows directly from Cauchy-Schwarz, but I don't see how. For $n=2$ it is easily proven (see below), but not for $n>2$. So my questions are:

1. How can relation (3) be proven for arbitrary $n\,$?
2. Can this be generalized into something of the form $\|x\|_{p} \leq C \|x\|_{q}$ for arbitrary $0<p < q\,$?
3. Do any of the relations also hold for infinite-dimensional spaces, i.e. in $l^p$ spaces?

---

Notes:

$\|x\|_{1}^{2} = |x_{1}|^2 + |x_{2}|^2 + 2|x_{1}||x_{2}| \leq |x_{1}|^2 + |x_{2}|^2 + \big(|x_{1}|^2 + |x_{2}|^2\big) = 2|x_{1}|^2 + 2|x_{2}|^2$, hence  $=2\|x\|_{2}^{2}$
$\|x\|_{1} \leq \sqrt 2 \|x\|_{2}$.
This works because $|x_{1}|^2 + |x_{2}|^2 \geq 2|x_{1}\|x_{2}|$, but only because $(|x_{1}| - |x_{2}|)^2 \geq 0$, while for more than two terms $\big(|x_{1}| \pm |x_{2}| \pm \dotsb \pm |x_{n}|\big)^2 \geq 0$ gives an inequality that never gives the right signs for the cross terms.

Comment: Your first link (1) has exactly the equation you seek. Actually a version of Norberts excellent answer, generalized to measure spaces.

Comment: Probably a dead thread, but norms in finite dimensional spaces are equivalent, so one can always find c ad C such that $c\|x\|_p\leq  \|x\|_q\leq C\|x\|_p$.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

1. Using [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) we get for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$
   $$
   \Vert x\Vert_1=
   \sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i|=
   \sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i|\cdot 1\leq
   \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 1^2\right)^{1/2}=
   \sqrt{n}\Vert x\Vert_2
   $$
2. Such a bound does exist. Recall [Hölder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) 
   $$
   \sum\limits_{i=1}^n |a_i||b_i|\leq
   \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|a_i|^r\right)^{\frac{1}{r}}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|b_i|^{\frac{r}{r-1}}\right)^{1-\frac{1}{r}}
   $$
   Apply it to the case $|a_i|=|x_i|^p$, $|b_i|=1$ and $r=q/p>1$
   $$
   \sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p=
   \sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p\cdot 1\leq
   \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (|x_i|^p)^{\frac{q}{p}}\right)^{\frac{p}{q}}
   \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 1^{\frac{q}{q-p}}\right)^{1-\frac{p}{q}}=
   \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x_i|^q\right)^{\frac{p}{q}} n^{1-\frac{p}{q}}
   $$
   Then
   $$
   \Vert x\Vert_p=
   \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p\right)^{1/p}\leq
   \left(\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x_i|^q\right)^{\frac{p}{q}} n^{1-\frac{p}{q}}\right)^{1/p}=
   \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x_i|^q\right)^{\frac{1}{q}} n^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}=\\=
   n^{1/p-1/q}\Vert x\Vert_q
   $$
   In fact $C=n^{1/p-1/q}$ is the best possible constant.
3. For infinite dimensional case such inequality doesn't hold. For explanation see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114650/ellp-subseteq-ellq-for-0pq-infty-and-cdot-p-cdot-q/114652#114652).

Comment: Could you please comment on why C is the best possible constant?

Comment: @Arun, because for $x=(1,1,1,\ldots,1)$ this bound is attained

Comment: @Norbert: I'm trying to derive a similar bound for the case $p>q$. Any ideas about how to proceed ?

Comment: @AshokVardhan what does "similar" mean? Do you want to prove something like $\Vert x\Vert_p \leq C\Vert x\Vert_q$ for $p>q$ ?

Comment: @Norbert: Yes, by similar, I meant a bound that you mentioned in the above comment. Thanks.

Comment: Then the best constant C is 1.

Comment: Regarding 3. is it true that the $\sqrt{n}$ term from 1. can be replaced by $\sqrt{\mu(\mathrm{supp}(x))}$ and then, in cases where $\mu(\mathrm{supp}(x))$ is bounded, a constant would exist? Thinking about functions from e.g. $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JoelBosveld, correct

Comment: @Norbert It is well known that
$$
\|z\|_{\infty} \leq \|z\|_2 \leq \sqrt{d} \|z\|_{\infty},
$$
for every $z=(z_1,\cdots,z_d)\in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $\|z\|_{\infty}= \displaystyle\max_{i\in \{1,\dots,d\}} |z_i|$. Furthermore, the above inequalities in are sharp (i.e. the constants $\sqrt{d}$ and $1$ are optimal). Please is there a sharp inequalities between $\|z\|_{\infty}$ and $\|z\|_{p}$ for $p\geq 1$? Thanks.

Comment: @Student, the sharp inequalities are gave in my answer also work for $q=\infty$. The reason is that $\Vert x\Vert_\infty=\lim\limits_{q\to\infty}\Vert x\Vert_q$.

Comment: @Norbert Thanks a lot. That is $d^{1/p}$?

Comment: @Student, Right.

Comment: I see that Hölder's inequality is for $p,q \in [1,\infty]$ Does 2) holds when $p$, or $q$, are less than $1$? If so, why?

Comment: @CarlosH.Mendoza-Cardenas For p and q less than 1, the functions defined are no longer norms since they don’t verify the triangle inequality.

Comment: In fact, you don't need an additional explanation for the infinite-dimensional case, because the dimension $n$ appears in the optimal proportionality constant with a positive exponent.