# The Frobenius norm is not an operator norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

> **Definition:** Let matrix $A$ be $m$-by-$n$, let $\| \cdot\|_{\tilde{m}}$ be a vector norm on $\mathbb R^{m}$ and $\| \cdot\|_{\tilde{n}}$ be a vector norm on $\mathbb R^{n}$. Then $$\| A\|_{\tilde{m}\tilde{n}} := \max\limits_{x \in \mathbb R^{n} \setminus \{0\}} \frac{\| Ax\|_{\tilde{m}}}{\| x\|_{\tilde{n}}}$$ is called an *operator norm*.
>
> **Question:** prove that Frobenius norm is not an operator norm.
>
> **Remark:** you cannot suppose that the norm on $\mathbb R^{m}$ and the norm on the $\mathbb R^{n}$ are the same norm but in different space.For example: $\| \cdot\|_2 $in $\mathbb R^{n}$ and $\| \cdot\|_2 $ in $\mathbb R^{m}$ .

Comment: no, I have tried for two days but without any progress. I asked a friend for help, but he didn't make it.

Comment: Maybe you can show us *what exactly* you *have* tried.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question gets downvoted. Obviously, the standard argument with the identity matrix does not work here (or is not straightforward to apply) as different vector norms are used in the domain and range of $A$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2600330/339790

Answer (score 0):

Frobenius matrix norm $\Vert A \Vert_F$ is defined for an $m \times n$ real matrix $A = [a_{ij}]$ as follows:

$$
\Vert A \Vert_F = \sqrt{   \sum\limits_{i = 1}^m \ \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n  \ \
| a_{ij} |^2   }
$$

Operator norm $\Vert A \Vert $ is defined for an $m \times n$ real matrix $A = [a_{ij}]$ as follows:

$$
\Vert A \Vert  = \max\limits_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbf{R}^n \backslash \{\mathbf{0}\}} \ \left[
 {\Vert A \mathbf{x} \Vert_m \over \Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert_n} \right]
$$

An important property of the operator norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is that
$$
\Vert I \Vert = 1
$$
where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

For the Frobenius norm, we see that
$$
\Vert I \Vert_F = \sqrt{1 + 1 + \cdots + 1} = \sqrt{n}
$$

This calculation establishes that the Frobenius norm is not an operator norm
for all $n \times n$ matrices for which $n \geq 2$.