# How to estimate a Lipschitz constant for a transformation? $T(x,y)=(u,v)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider a transformation $T(x,y)=(u,v)$ defined on (the unit square $E\ $): $0\leq x\leq 1$, $0\leq y\leq 1$. Where $$u=2x^2+6xy-4x^3/3-3xy^2, \ \ \ v=x^3-y^2 $$
Show that an estimate for the Lipschitz constant $M$ on $E$ is $M=\sqrt{65}$

By Lipschitz constant $M$ we mean $$ |T(p)-T(q)|\leq M|p-q|,\ \ p,q\in E$$ Since $T$ is of class $C'$ we know that $T$ is Lipschitz, I tried doing $|(u,v)-(u',v')|$ but it doesn't seems to be a good way. The hint says maximize the absolute value of derivatives arriving at the matrix $$\left(\begin{array}{rc} 4 & 6\\
3 & 2 \end{array}\right) $$ But I don't see how to arrive to this matrix nor how this can help. Please any guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of $T$ at $(x,y)$ is $$J(T)(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}4x+6y-4x^2-3y^2 & 6x - 6xy \\ 3x^2 & -2y\end{bmatrix}.$$

Maximizing the absolute value of each entry (over $x,y \in [0,1]$) individually leads to the matrix in the hint.

---

In general, we have the linear approximation $T(q) \approx T(p) + [J(T)(p)](q-p)$ when $q$ is close to $p$, so the idea is that
$$|T(q)-T(p)| \approx |[J(T)(p)](q-p)|.$$

The right-hand side is bounded by $M |q-p|$ where $M$ is the operator norm (largest singular value) of the Jacobian. The [operator norm is bounded by the Frobenius norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252819/why-is-frobenius-norm-of-a-matrix-greater-than-or-equal-to-the-2-norm) (square root of sum of squares of entries, or equivalently, square root of sum of squares of singular values). Using the matrix in the hint, the Frobenius norm is $\sqrt{4^2+6^2+3^2+2^2}=\sqrt{65}$.

Comment: Thanks, this is a clear way to approach this problems.