# Why is the function $\|\mathbf{J}\|_{\infty}$ $1$-Lipschitz w.r.t to the Euclidean norm?

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics, lipschitz-functions

Assume that $\mathbf{J} = \{ J \}_{ij}$ are centered independent standard Gaussian with variance $1/n$ random variables for $i, j = 1, \dots, n$. Why is the function $\|\mathbf{J}\|_{\infty}$ then $1/n$-Lipschitz w.r.t to the Euclidean norm, that is,
$$
\left|
  \sup_{\|u\| = 1} \langle u, \mathbf{J}u \rangle
- \sup_{\|v\| = 1} \langle v, \mathbf{J}v \rangle
\right|
\leq
\frac{1}{n} \|u - v\|_2 .
$$
Thus, it has a sub-Gaussian tail which is
$$
P(\|\mathbf{J}\|_{\infty} - E[\|\mathbf{J}\|_{\infty}] \geq x)
\leq
e^{-n x^2 / 2}.
$$

The original statement is as follows.

> Moreover, it is easy to see that
> $$
> \|\mathbf{J}\|_\infty = \sup_{\|u\| = 1} \langle u, \mathbf{J} u \rangle
> $$
> has sub-Gaussian tail.
> Indeed, is is a Lipschitz function of the Gaussian entries of $\mathbf{J}$ (with respect to the Euclidean norm) with constant bounded by $N^{-1/2}$ so that by Herbst argument (see [24, 25]), we have the concentration inequality
> $$
>   P(\|\mathbf{J}\|_\infty \geq E[\|\mathbf{J}\|_\infty] + x)
>   \leq
>   e^{-\frac{1}{2} N x^2} .
> $$

Comment: Isn't your first inequality the $1/n$-Lipschitzness of the $\ell_2$-norm instead of $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ ?

Comment: The statement that you want is not true (I think) almost surely. Would having high probability be enough?

Comment: @PhoemueX I add the original statement.

Comment: @StratosFair That is Lip with respect to the Euclidean norm.

Comment: @PhoemueX How to prove it is Lip with high probability?

Comment: I think you should prove Lipschitzness wrt to the entries in $J$. Please see Theorem 5.8 here https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~arinaldo/Teaching/36755/F16/Scribed_Lectures/LEC0914.pdf

Comment: @Mahdi Yes, I try to use this theorem. My question is how to prove the Lip of $||J||_{\infty}$$.

Comment: @Hermi please see the answer below.

Comment: @Hermi I think you should edit the question and the title, based on my answer.

Comment: @Mahdi Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|\mathbf{J}\|_{\infty}$ can be considered as a function of $\{\mathbf{J}_{i,j}\}_{i,j\in [n]^2}$, denoted it by $f(\mathbf{J}_{1,1},\dots,\mathbf{J}_{n,n})$. Let $\mathbf{J}_{vec}=(\mathbf{J}_{1,1},\dots,\mathbf{J}_{n,n})\in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ represents the unrolled version of $\mathbf{J}$.
Based on Theorem 5.8  in lecture note [1], if we manage to show that $\|\mathbf{J}\|_{\infty}$ is $1$-Lipschitz in the sense that
$$
\|\mathbf{J}\|_{\infty} - \|\mathbf{J'}\|_{\infty} \leq \| \mathbf{J}_{vec}- \mathbf{J'}_{vec} \|_2
$$

Then, we are done. Consider

$$
\sup_{||u||=1}<u, \mathbf{J}u>-\sup_{||v||=1}<v, \mathbf{J'}v>  \\
\leq \sup_{||u||=1}<u, \mathbf{J}u>-<u, \mathbf{J'}u> 
$$
Then, $\sup_{||u||=1}<u, \mathbf{J}u>-<u, \mathbf{J'}u>=\sup_{||u||=1}<u, (\mathbf{J}-\mathbf{J'})u> = \|\mathbf{J}-\mathbf{J'}\|_2$

where $\|\mathbf{J}-\mathbf{J'}\|_2$ is the matrix $\ell_2$ norm. Then, by a standard result (for a proof see [2]) we have  $\|\mathbf{J}-\mathbf{J'}\|_2 \leq  \|\mathbf{J}-\mathbf{J'}\|_F$ where $\|\mathbf{J}-\mathbf{J'}\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm. Finally note that $\|\mathbf{J}-\mathbf{J'}\|_F = \| \mathbf{J}_{vec}- \mathbf{J'}_{vec} \|_2$

[1][https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~arinaldo/Teaching/36755/F16/Scribed_Lectures/LEC0914.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Earinaldo/Teaching/36755/F16/Scribed_Lectures/LEC0914.pdf)

[2] [Why is the Frobenius norm of a matrix greater than or equal to the spectral norm?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252819/why-is-the-frobenius-norm-of-a-matrix-greater-than-or-equal-to-the-spectral-norm)

Comment: Thanks. Why do we have $\sup_{||u||=1}<u, (\mathbf{J}-\mathbf{J'})u> = \|\mathbf{J}-\mathbf{J'}\|_2?$ Isn't it $\sup_{||u||=1}<u, (\mathbf{J}-\mathbf{J'})u> = \|\mathbf{J}-\mathbf{J'}\|_\infty?$

Comment: Sorry, from the definition of $\|\|_\infty$, $\|A\|_\infty=\sup_{\|x\|_\infty=1}\|Ax\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: @Hermi you are right. Why this definition of $\|A\|_\infty=\sup_{\|x\|_\infty=1}\|Ax\|_{\infty}$ is equivalent with the definition in the question?

Comment: I do not know... the author says "it is easy to see that $\|J\|_\infty=\sup <x, Jx>$.  Also, I think $\|A\|_2=\sup <Ax, Ax>$?