# Estimate bounds on Minkowski distance from point to a segment in Lp space

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

### Assumptions

Let

$L_p(x,y)=(\sum_i|x_i - y_i|^p)^{1/p}$ (Minkowski metric),

$a,b$ be arbitrary $n$-dimensional points,

$c$ be a point that satisfies  $L_p(a,b) = L_p(a,c) + L_p(c,b)$, i.e., a point in $L_p$-metric segment between $a$ and $b$,

$t$ be another point (possibly outside the segment).

$1 \leq p \leq \infty$

$1 \leq q \leq \infty$

$L_q(a,t)$, $L_q(b,t)$, $L_p(a,b)$ are known and finite.

### The question

I'd like to estimate (tight) bounds on distance $L_q(c,t)$, preferably without referring to $a,b,c,t$ as points/vectors, instead using metrics only, however if this is necessary I'll accept that.

Are there any suggestions how to solve the above problem?

### Alternative question

Alternatively to the above, it would be enough to me to show that $L_q(c,t) \leq \max\{L_q(a,t), L_q(b,t)\}$.

Note, it is easy to show that the above condition is false for $1 \leq p < q \leq \infty$, given e.g., $p=1, q=2$ (draw it in 2D). However how to prove this for $1 \leq q \leq p \leq \infty$ or designate other bounds on $p$ and $q$ for which the condition is true?

**Possible hint**

For $q \leq p$ the following is true ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/218046/68706)):

$L_p(x,y) \leq L_q(x,y) \leq n^{1/q - 1/p} L_p(x,y)$

where $n$ is dimensionality of $L_p$ space.