# Some proof by induction

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, induction

I want to prove $|x_1\cdot x_2\cdots x_n| \leq |x_1|^n+\cdots +|x_n|^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^T \in \mathbb{R}^n$. For $n=1$ and $n=2$ its obvious. Assuming it holds for one $n$ we obtain

$$|x_1\cdot x_2\cdots x_n\cdot x_{n+1}| \leq (|x_1|^n+\cdots +|x_n|^n)|x_{n+1}|.$$

From here I couldn't proceed.

Comment: We may consider $\sqrt[n]{|x_1...x_n|\,}\leq\frac1n\|{\bf x}\|_{l_1}\leq\|{\bf x}\|_{l_n}$, where the first bound is [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_Inequality) and the second is the [$l_p$ norm bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218046/relations-between-p-norms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: pick the largest of the $|x_i|$s. For instance, for $k=2$ we have $$|ab|\leqslant \max\{|a|,|b|\}^2 \leqslant |a|^2+|b|^2.$$ Do similarly for $k=n$.